# Are there humanoid aliens that have fewer facial characteristics rather than more?

Tags: star-trek, aliens

Most of the aliens that I've seen on Star Trek that are humanoid have more features on their face than humans rather than less.

I know that this is probably easy for the special effects crew to just add onto the actors' face rather than try to subtract from it...but other than the Changelings, are there any creatures that have less facial features?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figure the [Ancient humanoids](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ancient_humanoid) fit your description.  They're the in-universe explanation for why the Star Trek universe is filled with so many humanoid beings from hundreds of different worlds.  They seeded the galaxy with life so that life ended up looking similar to them.

But, consider the racism inherent in your question.  You're starting with humans as the default and asking why other species are more featured than them.  Wouldn't an equally valid question be why do humans, amongst the dozens of humanoid creatures in the galaxy, have the *least* facial characteristics?  I figure they're the ones who stand out among the galaxy's people as being so *boring* in their facial structure.

Comment: My question was asked from the humanoid standpoint. The definition of humanoid is human-like. My question was meant to be a direct comparison to humans.

Comment: I think there would only be racism inherent in this question if it were asked in-universe.

Comment: Can't really be racist against something that doesn't exist. ;)

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Oh I see how it is, you're a non-fictionist too! :p

Comment: @Keen no no no, I'm a realist ;P

Comment: @OghmaOsiris LOL oh man, that's a terrible pun.

Comment: I don't see how it can be racist at all, since the series is primarily about humans and produced by humans and all the actors are humans (well, most - I don't know if tribbles get a SAG card or not).  With that in mind, it's not at all racist.

Comment: Actually if it were asked in Universe it would be speciesist - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speciesist

Comment: Surface features should ideally reduce as a species evolves to be more and more dependent on their intelligence rather than biological characteristics. They will rely less on on facial features and organs for protection from the environment, recognition, sensory input, communication etc.

Comment: @HNL How human-centric of you! But seriously, I agree that the question is in no way racist/speciesist. It's a valid question. "Are there species with fewer features with humans rather than more" is a question based on an observation, not a value judgment. You could just as easily decide that it was "racist" against humans for implying that we have such overly simplified features, rather than being "racist" against aliens for having such complex features. Seriously, just noticing differences between species is not automatically racist/discriminatory in and of itself.